# curl POST not giving me result

Tags: json, curl, post, rpc

I'm trying to do a curl POST request for json-rpc however it's not giving me any error when I use it and I'm unsure what I'm doing incorrectly. Been trying to figure out how to do it for an hour

The request I'm trying to perform:

```
http post https://rpc.nearprotocol.com jsonrpc=2.0 
method=query params:='["account/near.test", ""]' id=dontcare
```

I've tried:

````
curl -X POST https://rpc.nearprotocol.com -d 
'{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"query", 
"account/near.test”:”snailbail45"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'```
````

However it's just returning the next line.

This Works for me though:

```
curl -X POST https://rpc.nearprotocol.com -d    
'{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"status"}' -H 'Content-Type:     
application/json'
```

What am I doing incorrectly in the first one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have stylized quotation marks (`”` instead of `"`) between `test` and `snailbail45`:

```
"account/near.test”:”snailbail45"
```

Comment: Good catch haha